# How to I loop my program until they have filled it properly when I'm using an if statement?

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

How do I loop this program until they have it filled right? My program ends if the requirements aren't entered. I know while statements makes loops, but how do I do it if I'm using if statements like the one on my program below? Thank you!

```
name = input('Name(FN/MN/LN): ')
if len(name) == 0:
    print ('Error! Please enter your real name!')
    sys.exit()
import re
nickname = input('Preferred name/nickname: ')
if len(name) == 0:
    print ('Error! Please enter a nickname!')
    sys.exit()
nickname=nickname.lower()
if not re.match('^[a-z]*$', nickname):
    print ('Error! Only letters allowed!')
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: `if not all(i.isalpha() for i in nickname.split()): print('Only letters allowed')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you just need to put a while loop above all of your `if`s:

```
import re

while True:
    name = input('Name(FN/MN/LN): ')
    if len(name) == 0:
        print ('Error! Please enter your real name!')
        continue #Try again
    break # len(name) is not 0, continue

while True:
    nickname = input('Preferred name/nickname: ')
    if len(nickame) == 0: #fixed this to nickname
        print ('Error! Please enter a nickname!')
        continue
    break

nickname=nickname.lower()
if not re.match('^[a-z]*$', nickname):
    print ('Error! Only letters allowed!')
    sys.exit()
```

That's all, wasn't very difficult, was it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a while-loop, and `break` when your condition matches:

```
while True:
    name = input('Name(FN/MN/LN): ')
    if len(name) == 0:
        print ('Error! Please enter your real name!')
        continue
    break
print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a call to `sys.exit()` will end you program right away. I'm pretty sure that this is not what you want to do here. Now If you want to control the user's input your code should be as follows:

```
s = input("input request")
while s is not correct input:
    print("error message")
    s = input("new request")
```